# using a While loop to control the value of a keyframe in a timeline in Javafx

Tags: loops, javafx, while-loop, timeline, keyframe

i want to create an animation where the ball will move in one of the 4 sectors of a circle randomly.this will happen 5 times.so,i create a while loop(i<5) and call the random function.i then create an if loop and attach some x and y values according to the random fn value.i then create an timeline object inside the while loop and in the key frame value,i use these x and y values.but when i run the program,what happens is that all the values are being created(x and y values seen through println) but only the last x and y value(for i=5)is being rendered in the screen.the animations for the previous values(1<=i<=4)are not being rendered.Please advise where have i gone wrong?

public function run(args:String[])
{

var i=0;
  while(i<5)
  {
    var z=gety();
    println(z);
   // var relativeTime:Duration=0s;
    if(z==1)
    {xbind=120;
          ybind=80;
          }
          else if(z==2)
          {xbind=120;
ybind=120;
          }
          else if(z==3)
          {
                  xbind=80;
ybind=120;
          }
          else if(z==4)
          {
xbind=80;
ybind=80;
          }

var t:Timeline=Timeline{

```
 //time: bind pos with inverse;
 repeatCount: Timeline.INDEFINITE
    autoReverse: true

   keyFrames:
       [


       KeyFrame{
   time: 0s values: [ x => 100.0,y => 100.0]},
   KeyFrame{time: 2s values:[x => xbind tween Interpolator.LINEAR,
   y =>  ybind tween Interpolator.LINEAR,]
 },
  ]


    }//end timeline

    i++;
    t.play();
Thread.sleep(2000);
 }//end while
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Updating bound values for animation in a loop seems to be a relatively common anti-pattern.  Updating bound values within a Timeline is a better solution.  Study [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435911/updating-a-shape-in-scene-with-a-for-loop-using-javafx/2446266#2446266) for a code fragment. Note also that using a Stage means you don't need to put logic in a run() function.